# Does Visual Studio Code support language servers written in C#

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've taken a look at the VS Code documentation on creating a language server but can only see reference to a nodejs implementation.  Is there SDK support for creating a language server written in C#?  Ultimately this would be a DNX or Core 1.0 library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter which language is being used to create a language server. **as long as you are able to communicate with it** from within Visual Studio Code.
A common way to establish the communication is made by using the [VSCode Language Server Protocol](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-protocol).

You can build your language service in C#, Java, C++, Delphi or whatever language as long as you create a command line server which is able to handle that protocol.

You can see how a language server in C# is implemented when you take a look at the [OmniSharp project](http://www.omnisharp.net/).

Comment: Thanks Wosi. I'll take a look at OmniSharp.